# Ruby - How to remove space after some characters?

Tags: ruby, string, truncate

I need to remove white spaces after some characters, not all of them. I want to remove whites spaces after these chars: I,R,P,O. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
"I ".gsub(/(?<=[IRPO]) /, "") # => "I"
"A ".gsub(/(?<=[IRPO]) /, "") # => "A "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
" P  $ R   3I&".gsub(/([IRPO])\s+/,'\1')
  #=> " P$ R3I&"
```